# Entity Framework Inheritance vs Tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, database-design

Ok I am very new to creating databases with Entity in mind.

I have a Master table which is going to have:

```
departmentID
functionID
processID
procedureID
```

Each of those ID's need to point to a specific list of information.  Which is name, description and owner of course they link back to each ID in the master table.

My question is, should I make 4 separate tables or create one table since the information is the same in all the tables except one.

The `procedureID` will actually need to have an extra field for `documentID` to point to a specific document.

Is it possible and a good idea to make one table and add some inheritance, or is it better to make 4 separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting data into a number of related tables brings many advantages over one single table. Also by having data held in separate tables, it is simple to add records that are not yet needed but may be in the future. You can also create your corresponding objects for each table in your code. Also it would be more difficult to split the data into separate tables in the future if somehow you need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, pondering it over the weekend i came to the same conclusion.